# OpenGL / OpenTK : display FBO rendered on background thread in OpenGL-control

Tags: multithreading, opengl, opentk, fbo

I'm using OpenGL via OpenTK and I'm rendering to a FramebufferObject in a background thread.
Now after each rendered frame, I want to display (part(s) of) the FBO in one or more OpenGL controls in my UI.

How does that work ?

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

- If your drivers support context sharing, you can bind the FBO texture on your OpenGL controls and display that directly (bind texture, render quad, done). Simple and fast - just make sure to synchronize your rendering with the display.
- If your drivers don't, you'll have to readback the results of the rendering into a Bitmap object (or equivalent) via GL.ReadPixels. You can then re-upload them to your other OpenGL controls as textures or display them directly on non-OpenGL controls.

By default, OpenTK will always try to share contexts. Unfortunately, Intel drivers don't support context sharing, so you cannot use the first approach there.

Comment: What would be the best way to "synchronize rendering with the display" ?

Comment: GraphicsContext.CurrentContext.VSync = true;